# Can a HttpSession object be migraed from one VM to anoher VM?

Tags: java, session, servlets

Can session object be migrated from one VM to another VM or It passivated in one VM and activated in other VM? How?

Comment: Zero out of your 18 previous questions have an accepted answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The contents of the session are serialized (if they implement `Serializable`) on the hard disk whenever the servlet container stops. You can use the same technique to "migrate" it. [`ObjectOutputStream`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html) can give you some directions.

Answer (score 2):

You may be looking for what's usually called *HTTP Session Replication*. Many application servers offer it, in different ways. See e.g. the [Tomcat Clustering/Session Replication HOW-TO](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/cluster-howto.html).